# Not able to run CDatacollection demo in my ubuntu x86 machine

Tags: kaa

I installed a sandbox image in my vb successfully and then I
downloaded *CDatacollection demo C sdk*. But when I run the
application I got the following error, not sure what is the issue.
Kindly let me know, how can I fix this?

```
sudo ./build.sh build

================================== BUILD_TYPE = (Default) KAA_PLATFORM = posix KAA_MAX_LOG_LEVEL = 3
================================== BOOTSTRAP ENABLED PROFILE ENABLED USER EXTENSION ENABLED CONFIGURATION ENABLED EVENTS ENABLED LOGGING
ENABLED NOTIFICATION ENABLED ENCRYPTION ENABLED KAA WILL BE
INSTALLED TO  /usr/local
-- Configuring done CMake Error at targets/posix/CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_library):   Cannot find source file:

    INTERFACE
```

Tried these extensions:

```
.c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp   .hxx .in .txx
```

Regards Rurban

Answer (score 0):

Rurban!

We have investigated your problem. CMake fails to configure because INTERFACE library targets are not supported in CMake 2.x version. 
To resolve the issue, try to update CMake to version 3.0.2 or later.

We also have opened the ticket to update the cmake_minimum_required() statement in the Kaa C SDK sample applications. You can see it here -- http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/APP-527.

Please let me know if the problem has been solved.

Best regards, 
Maksim